# Apache airflow task: java: command not found

Tags: java, python, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I'm running `Apache Airflow` using `Docker`. I have installed `OpenJDK12` and defined its variables in both of:
`~/.bachrc`
`/usr/local/airflow/.bachrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/src/jdk-12
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

and I can see `Java` is running normally especially when I run the `Task` from the `command line` :

```
airflow test ip-importer Download 2020-2-19
```

where it's working properly without errors , where the task is for :

> Executing java command to run a Jar file

But now when I schedule the task on the `webserver UI` and when I run it, It doesn't run properly and gives me this error:

> [2020-02-18 00:46:39,941] {{bash_operator.py:126}} INFO -
>   /tmp/airflowtmpdzijcupu/Download886rmbol: line 1: java: command not
>   found

so seems like **It's unable to see the defined paths for Java**.

1. **Any hints / ideas for how to solve this issue ?**
2. ***Another*** question , In case if the java application has thrown an exception/error , Airflow doesn't assume it as an error , it assumes it as a `succeeded task` , **Could you advise how to enforce airflow to assume the exception as a real interrupter for the task ?**

Comment: `.bashrc` (**not** `.bachrc`) and in the homefolder for the `airflow` user.

Comment: Hi @ElliottFrisch sorry it's a typs .. I meant `.bashrc` . and yes I added it to the home folder of `airflow` and the same

Comment: @Jason4Ever did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if **/usr/bin** folder from Docker container has the executable file pointing out to Java cmd.   If not, create one with the following cmd:

Example:

```
ln -s /usr/local/airflow/java/jdk1.8.0_161-x64/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```